# IID linking error with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, com

I've got a problem with trying to link IIDs in VS2013.

I've searched around and tried suggested fixes, but they don't seem to work.

I've never done COM before this, so I may just be missing a step in the process.

I am trying to create a COM class in one library, which will then be linked and used by other projects.

What I've done is create this IDL file:

```
[
    uuid(626FCA47-CC2C-4604-9F46-223607BAB6C7), version(1.0), helpstring("XScriptingObjectClass")
]
library XScriptingObjectLib
{
    [
        uuid(268AE16D-7179-4569-9851-B86621346B4F), helpstring("Main interface for XScriptingObject")
    ]
    interface IXScriptingObject : IDispatch
    {
            // functions removed so this post isn't 900 miles long.

    };

    [
        uuid(AD9B5251-B699-4DF5-B5AA-1C626FABDC93),
        helpstring("XScriptingObject Class")
    ]
    coclass CXScriptingObject
    {
        [default] interface IXScriptingObject;
    };


};
```

And then, I have a .h file for the interface that I've made:

```
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IXScriptingObject;

MIDL_INTERFACE("268AE16D-7179-4569-9851-B86621346B4F")
IXScriptingObject : public IDispatch
{
}
```

I've got a non interface class as well that inherits from the interface, and is setup like what I thought was correct:

```
#pragma once
#include "IXScriptingObject.h"
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CXScriptingObject;
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IXScriptingObject;


class ATL_NO_VTABLE CXScriptingObject : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CXScriptingObject, &CLSID_CXScriptingObject>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IXScriptingObject, &IID_IXScriptingObject>
{
public:
    long m_lRefCount;

    DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CXScriptingObject)
    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CXScriptingObject)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IXScriptingObject)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    END_COM_MAP()

    //::ATL::CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> m_spHtmlDoc;
};
```

Everything will build for this library.   Every project consuming this library will build unless I try to use CComObject to create an instance of the object.  This is when the linker error for the IID occurs.   The linker errors occur in the OTHER projects that are trying to consume this library, even though the instantiation is being done in the library code itself.

Have I missed a step, or am I going about this completely wrong?   I tried one suggestion of including the auto generated .h/.c files generated from the IDL file.  It didn't seem to work.   The projects that consume this library end up complaining that the IID is already defined elsewhere if I do that..

I also tried explicitly linking the library in with full paths instead of relative.   No dice there either.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't create your own .h file with the interface declaration, that's the job of MIDL.  It generates a xxxx_i.h file, note that it already has those EXTERN_C consts.  Client code can then use the __uuidof keyword to get the iid and clsid without a need for linking xxxx_i.c.  The #import directive is notable, a simple way for client code to use the COM server with auto-generated smart pointer wrappers.

Comment: Good description, but lacks important piece: what is the linker error exactly? And yes you don't need to define IID yourself, since you can easily and reliably import IDL/TLB.

Comment: I get LNK2001.  I tried not using my own interface declaration and just using the .H that was provided.  It caused a meltdown.

I discovered that including the autogenerated .c file within my .CPP file that derives from the interface causes the linking to succeed.   It seems like a strange way to get it going though.

Comment: This is not quite getting better. Even with it building, trying to instantiate this class causes stack exceptions.

Does anyone know if there is some crucial step that is required for it to work?

The crash is happening at some point BEFORE my code is hit (shown above). If I comment this code out, it proceeds fine.

Also, this is in a project that exports a .lib. I am not sure if this has any impact on things, since I've seen that most examples seem to involve DLLs.

Comment: I tried using CoCreateInstance instead of ComObject's CreateInstance, and it just gives me the error code of "Class Not Registered". My best guess for that is, since it's not a DLL, I can't register it? (Maybe I can?)

Thanks again.